# Visual Studio 2008: How can I change the name of my dll file, if is it in use?

Tags: visual-studio

1. I have the project **MyProject**
2. I build the solution and I get the **MyProject.dll** file.
3. I load the file in some program.
4. I make some changes in my solution and I hit the build button. I receive this error:

*`Unable to copy file ".dll" to "bin\Debug\.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\.dll' because it is being used by another process.`*

Do I have the posibility in this case, if my .dll file is used by another program, that the Visual Studio should generate a MyProject1(2,3..).dll?

Comment: Why would you have a program load the dll from the build output folder?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and I'm not sure why you'd want it to. If your dll is being used by something else it should be located somewhere other than the project's output folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this directly, but it can be done manually. You could make it a macro (easier to change project settings) or an external program (requires modifying the vcproj as text or as xml); pseudo-code leaning towards an external C++ implementation:

```
bool CanWriteDll( dll )
{
  return FileOutputStream( dll ).is_open();
}

void BuildProject( proj )
{
  LaunchProcess( "devenv /Build " + proj ); //or "msbuild ..." if you will
}

string FindUniqueName( dll )
{
  string name = Path( dll ).NameWithoutExtension();
  string ext = Path( dll ).Extension();
  string newname;
  int i = 1;
  for( ; ; )
  {
    newname = name + ToString( i++ ) + ext;
    if( !FileExists( newname ) )
      return newname;
  }
}

void ModifyTargetName( proj, newName )
{
   Xml xml = OpenXmlFile( proj );
   XmlNode node = xml.FindNode( "Tool.VCLinkerTool.OutputFile" );
   node.SetValue( "$(OutDir)\" + newName );
   xml.WriteFile();
} 

  //main code
if( !CanWriteDll( dll ) )
  ModifyTargetName( proj, FindUniqueName( dll ) );
BuildProject( project );
```

This off course leaves the problem that you have to relaunch the app using the dll and tell it to use MyProject1.dll now. So if you have to close the application anyway, you might as well close it first, then build the dll, then open it again. In other words, Fredrik's and Chuck's comments are spot-on: you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place.